# Are tears considered as a crafted resource?

Tags: kittens-game

In kittens game, are unicorn tears considered as crafted resources and not affected by chronospheres? (unless the upgrade "flux condensator" is bought)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not.

Tears are a rare, luxury resource which doesn't count as *craftable*. This can be verified from [the source](https://bitbucket.org/bloodrizer/kitten-game/src/8557c5d06ad999a68e95256b1a9112934902c32e/resources.js?fileviewer=file-view-default#resources.js-140). Craftable resources have a `craftable` flag set to `true`.

For clarification, it is my understanding that tears are *always* lost during a reset. No matter if you have Chronospheres and/or Flux Condensator. They are among the [resources that are ignored](https://bitbucket.org/bloodrizer/kitten-game/src/8557c5d06ad999a68e95256b1a9112934902c32e/game.js?fileviewer=file-view-default#game.js-2006) during regular reset-related resource conservation calculation.